# question about component-based frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks

i read about that with component-based frameworks, like yii, you could reuse every component for you next project.

could someone give a real-life example of components (i hear this word all the time, but don't know what they exactly refer to) and how i could reuse them for my next project?

are codeigniter and kohana component based frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana, Yii, and CodeIgniter are all OO frameworks. They let you easily extend what is provided with your own functionality.

If you were making a website about books, for example, you could create a Book object that encapsulated whatever functions and properties you need to describe and manipulate books.

Later, when you do another website that involves books, you can simply re-use the Book object created for the first site.

Comment: so Object oriented frameworks are the same as component based frameworks? but there got to be some differences, why whould prado and yii always boast about that they are component driven. what do they mean besides the basic oop structure?

Comment: "Object" and "Component" often mean the same thing. In some cases a "Component" is a set of several pieces which are consumed together. In other frameworks, such as CI or Yii, a component is simply an object that conforms to one or more interfaces so that they can be consumed in the application. Take a look at this page:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/basics.component